# Passing a string vector to a function and function prototype issue c++

Tags: c++, function, vector

In this example, the compiler says the function "list" doesn't have a definition, despite me writing one below. If I move the function definition to the top so there is no prototype, it compiles fine.

Can someone explain what's happening here?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    void stuff();
    void list(vector<string> things);

    bool alive = true;

    int main()

    {
       vector<string> things;
       things.push_back("Lots");
       things.push_back("Of");
       things.push_back("Things");

       do
       {
         cout << "What do you want to do?\n\n" << endl;
         string input;
         cin >> input;

         if (input == "stuff")
         {
            stuff();
         }
         if (input == "list")
         {
            list();
         }
       } while (alive);

       return 0;
     }

   void list()
     {
       cout << "The things are:\n\n";
       for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); ++i)
       {
         cout << things[i] << endl;
       }
     }

    void stuff()
     {
       cout << "Some stuff" << endl;
     }
```

Comment: [*error C2660: 'list': function does not take 0 arguments*](https://godbolt.org/g/UVtHCj) - This doesn't even have the word "definition".

Comment: Well I apologise for the incorrect error. I tried numerous things before posting and the definition error was the most prevalent. I guess this time just happened to be different and I didn't notice.

Comment: You have a prototype for `void list(vector<string> things);`, but NOT for `void list();`. Perhaps you simply need to supply the argument to the `list()` function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list` [function definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition) signature differs from your [function declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration). The function signature should be the same. Your function definition signature should also accept one parameter:

```
void list(std::vector<string> things)
{
    std::cout << "The things are:\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < things.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << things[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

And in your program you call the function with:

```
list();
```

where it should be:

```
list(things);
```

Comment: Now the compiler says "error C2660: 'list': function does not take 0 arguments" and refers the the call to `list`.

Comment: @MrSteve I've addressed that in my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

`void list(vector<string> things);` is not the same as `void list()`. You need to actually define your function as void `list(vector<string> things)` not just the prototype.